# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group' SinglePageApp1. Get["/"] Nancy

Tags: c#, linq, get, nancy

I try to make a class with NancyModules and GET string on URL but method 'Get' tells that:

> "Error    CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'method group'  ...."

My Code:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Web; using Nancy; using System.Text;

namespace SinglePageApp1 {
    public class BloodPresureNancy : NancyModule
    {
        public BloodPresureNancy()
        {

            // Get dasn't work
            Get["/"] = _ => "Heloooo";
        }
    } 
}
```

[image]

I add references: Nancy, Nancy.Hosting.asp and it isn't working.

Answer (score 27):

What version of Nancy are you currently using? That syntax should work on versions 1.x. However, I think that Nancy recently made a change to the way that you register routes for their upcoming 2.0 release. If you take a look at the samples they have on github https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Self/TestModule.cs. You will see that you don't index into the different verbs  anymore like you are doing above, you actually reference them like you would a Method. Try changing your code to be

```
    Get("/", _ => {
        //do work here
     });
```

instead and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/2441

Specifically:

> the wiki will not be updates as the 2.0 packages comes out of pre-release, until then all changes are considered as being pending =)

Ie. The magic custom indexer syntax that allowed you to do this:

```
Get["/"] = ...
```

Is gone in the Nancy 2.x releases.

However, *all* the documentation currently still refers to the current (ie. 1.4.x versions); so...

tldr; That syntax is old and gone in the new version of Nancy. Use `Get(...)`, `Post(...)`, etc if you're using the new version of Nancy.

Answer (score 2):

While this is most likely not the right way of doing it, it does work:

```
Get("/test/{category}", parameters => { return "My category is " + (Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue)parameters.category; });
```

Going to http://localhost/test/hello will return "My category is hello"